# Passing Data to a Child Window AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

So I am relatively new to front-end development and what I am trying to accomplish is opening a child window with my angular-chart.js template that I have created. Now the problem is the data that I have seems to not transfer over as well. Now I know that a child window does not have access to the data or DOM a parent does however what is the best way to pass the data I have over? I am utilizing Angular-Charts http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

**js:**

```
   $scope.openLargeGraph = function () {
                $scope.dataSample = "hi";
                console.log(dataSample)
                var childWindowForGraph = window.open('template.html', "", "width=950,height=850");
               childWindowForGraph.data =
                childWindowForGraph.moveTo(300, 50);
            };
```

**template.html:**

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 well"
         style="margin-bottom: 6px; padding: 3px; padding-left: 0px;
                max-height: 480px; overflow-y: auto;"
         ng-show="currentSample.viz == 'hbc'">
        <canvas id="panel1base" class="chart-base" height="400px"
                chart-type="'horizontalbar'"
                chart-labels="profile['detail']['freq-histogram'].labels"
                chart-data="[profile['detail']['freq-histogram'].data]"
                chart-legend="false"
                chart-colours="['#008080']"
                chart-legend="false"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as it is. You're trying to load a template outside angular's lifecycle.

You should be instead accessing that template through a route and associate a controller with it.

Comment: Why couldn't the data be passed up as a variable?

Comment: Angular-Charts works as an angular directive, that's why you need some angular context to be able to call it. Calling the template directly won't give you any angular context.

Comment: I am honestly confused

Comment: No worries, here's a plunkr with 2 routes explaining basic routing in Angular : https://plnkr.co/edit/VsFaYm5JEjQeJqmpKDhV?p=preview.

Comment: why couldn't I just load the chart library into the template? I am having more trouble moving the data over.

Comment: you can do that, but passing the data from one view/state to another, just like I did in the plunkr provided (there are other ways to pass on data)